# Connection Timeout Error on Amazon Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

I am trying to run an AWS Glue Command from AWS CLI to get my job started from an EC2 instance. This is the command

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name Connection_Test
```

But I get the following error:

```
ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

I have added a connection to the Glue Job but I still got the same answer. Do you know what could be? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Actually it connects to the endopoint created for the service but I am still getting the same answer

Comment: If you're getting the same error you haven't configured the endpoint properly

Answer (score 3):

These errors:

> ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL"

occur when your environment (in this case, an EC2 instance) is not able to communicate with the AWS service in question (`glue.us-east-1`).

You have two options to fix this:

1. Give your EC2 instance internet connectivity, with either an internet gateway or a NAT gateway. If you do this, traffic to the service will go over the public internet
2. Create an interface VPC endpoint for the service and deploy it in the same subnet as the EC2 instance. If you do this, traffic to the service will go over AWS private network

The second option is generally the best one, because connectivity to the endpoint will be faster, and because it allows you to keep your instance on a private network.

(The two options are not mutually exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your services are not able to communicate to each other within VPC.

Ensure that the security group that you use for your Glue connection has the following configurations,

```
Self referential Inbound Rule: {"Type":"All TCP","Protocol":"TCP","Port Range":"0-65535","Destination":"Same Security-group" }

Outbound Rule: {"Type":"All Traffic","Protocol":"ALL","Port Range":"ALL","Destination":"0.0.0.0/0"}
```

Also, make sure that you create a VPC endpoint (Gateway) for s3 so that your glue can access the files from S3 bucket.